# Error viewing the result of ee.Algorithms.CrossCorrelation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics, geostatistical-analyst

I am facing an issue when using ee.Algorithms.CrossCorrelation in Google Earth Engine. I am using an LST image and an NDVI image as input. The final product seems to have a visualization error since only the edges of the pixels are colored, as if the pixels were transformed into vectors. Has anyone encountered something similar?
When the visualization is not too close to the pixels, everything seems fine. However, as I zoom in on the image, the visualization appears as lines.

[image]

[image]

```
 var termal = imagem.select(termalBand).rename('TERMAL');
  var ndvi = imagem.normalizedDifference([nirBand, redBand]).rename('NDVI');
  var ndvimin = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: area_estudo,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).values().get(0));

  var ndvimax = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: area_estudo,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).values().get(0));

  var proporcao_veg = ndvi.subtract(ndvimin).divide(ndvimax.subtract(ndvimin)).pow(ee.Number(2));
  var emissividade = proporcao_veg.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EM');
  var LTS = termal.expression(
    '(T/(1+(W*(T/P))*log(e)))-273.15',{
    'T': termal,
    'W': w,
    'P': p,
    'e': emissividade.select('EM')
  }).rename('LTS');


//Correlação Cruzada entre LTS e NDVI
var maxGap = 0;
var windowSize = 3;
var maxMaskedFrac = 0;
var crossCorrelation = ee.Algorithms.CrossCorrelation(LTS.select('LTS'), ndvi.select('NDVI'), maxGap, windowSize, maxMaskedFrac);
var crossCorrelationCoeff = crossCorrelation.select('correlationCoeff').rename('crossCorrelation');

// Adicionar layers
Map.addLayer(imagem.clip(area_estudo), {bands: rgbBands, min: 0.0, max: 0.3}, 'Landsat_' + ano + '_S' + (semestre + 1), 0); 
Map.addLayer(LTS.clip(area_estudo), {bands: ['LTS'], min: 25, max: 45, palette: paleta_termal}, 'Temperatura_' + ano + '_S' + (semestre + 1), 0); 
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(area_estudo), {bands: ['NDVI'], min: 0.09, max: 0.64, palette: paleta_ndvi}, 'NDVI_' + ano + '_S' + (semestre + 1), 0); 
Map.addLayer(crossCorrelationCoeff.clip(area_estudo), {bands: ['crossCorrelation'], min: -1, max: 1, palette: paleta_cross}, 'CrossCorrelation_' + ano + '_S' + (semestre + 1), 0);
```